# Change default collation/character set

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I know this has been answered before but the solutions I found does not apply to my system (I've tested them).

I want to change the default collation in Mysql. It seems this is setted to latin1_swedish_ci and i want to change this to UTF8_general_ci.

The most frequently returning solution on the net was putting the default_character_set directive in my.ini with default value of utf8, but for some reason it gives an error.

this is the error. I hope someone can help me.

```
130502 15:45:17 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130502 15:45:17 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130502 15:45:17 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130502 15:45:17 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130502 15:45:17 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130502 15:45:17 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130502 15:45:17 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130502 15:45:17  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130502 15:45:18 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 2472751
130502 15:45:18 [ERROR] wampmysqld: unknown variable 'default-character-set=utf8'
130502 15:45:18 [ERROR] Aborting

130502 15:45:18  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130502 15:45:19  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2472751
130502 15:45:19 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: It did work. I just made a mistake, I created a table in an existing database with swedish collation.

To other people with this problem: you have to change the collation in your database too if you want to change it.