# Set default collation for create database

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set the default-default characterset for a new created mysql database.  Because I'm lazy, I will use "CREATE DATABASE blahblah;" without providing additional "CHARSET" or "DEFAULT COLLATE". After "SHOW CREATE DATABASE blahblah;" I see:

```
blahblah | CREATE DATABASE `blahblah` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */
```

Latin1? I need **utf8**. Let's change my.cnf and mysqld.cnf.

mysqld.conf (server config) is

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

.my.cnf (my local file) is

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

Just to by sure, let's restart the server, drop the database, create and... again latin1.

To be honest, I also tried character_set_server (underscores, instead of dashes), copy the entries to .my.conf back and forth... and there is still the f***g latin1.

So... did I made a typo? Do I miss any extra line somewhere? Is it impossible to set a default-default charset, so I need to provide them everytime I do a "create database..."?

Ubuntu 18.04.2, mysqld 5.7.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
(I am aware of the [Change default collation/character set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339922/change-default-collation-character-set), but it doesnt work)

Comment: `collation-server` seams it should be the correct one when looking into https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/sql/sql_db.cc#L327 -> `if (!create->default_table_charset)
create->default_table_charset= thd->variables.collation_server;`

Comment: ... unless this is not conf file is MySQL server is using, and MySQL uses a other one..